# How do I store barcode scanner result in history?

Tags: android

I want to store bar code scanner result in new activity please help me. in this case SQLight database use?

Here is my code:

```
public class Barcode_Activity extends AppCompatActivity implements ZXingScannerView.ResultHandler {

    private ZXingScannerView mScannerView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.barcode_activity);

        mScannerView = new ZXingScannerView(this);
        setContentView(mScannerView);
    }

    @Override
    public void handleResult(Result result) {
        Log.v("TAG", result.getText());
        Log.v("TAG", result.getBarcodeFormat().toString());
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Scan Result");
        builder.setMessage(result.getText());
        AlertDialog alert1 = builder.create();
        alert1.show();

        mScannerView.resumeCameraPreview(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        mScannerView.setResultHandler(this);
        mScannerView.startCamera();
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mScannerView.stopCamera();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
@Override
public void handleResult(Result result) {
    Log.v("TAG", result.getText());
    Log.v("TAG", result.getBarcodeFormat().toString());
    String ResultString = result.getBarcodeFormat().toString();
    Intent i = new Intent(this, Barcode_Activity.class);
    i.putExtra("qrresult", ResultString);
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Scan Result");
    builder.setMessage(result.getText());
    AlertDialog alert1 = builder.create();
    alert1.show();

    mScannerView.resumeCameraPreview(this);
}
```

In the next activity you can get the result as

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String ResultString= intent.getExtras().getString("qrresult");
```

Also you can call the database as necessary.

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

You can put the result in a `bundle` or `SharedPreferences`